# Column values distributed to adjacent columns

Tags: python, csv

How can I to take a .csv file with:

A B C

1 2 3

4 5 6

In order to make:

1 2

1 3

4 5

4 6

Basically creating  a new column with the values distributed among consecutive columns to create a redundant first column with unique values.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, in order to get answer, please read and follow this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hey all! I'm really new to how this site works, my apologies if this wasn't the greatest post, but it's a thing that has been stumping me, and it's so basic. I'm sure you all know how that goes! Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script can be used to read in a CSV file in the format you have given, a text file with spaced numbers. The header row is first skipped.

```
import csv

with open("input.csv", "r") as f_input, open("output.csv", "wb") as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=" ")
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=" ")
    headings = csv_input.next()     # skip the header row

    for row in csv_input:
        for col in row[1:]:
            csv_output.writerow([row[0], col])
```

**input.csv**

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

This input csv file will produce an output CSV file as follows:

**output.csv**

```
1 2
1 3
4 5
4 6
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I actually had a .csv, so all I had to do was include the "," where it specifies the delimiter instead of " ".